# What exactly does it mean in Javascript to always have numbers as 64 floating points?

Tags: javascript, numbers, primitive

I'm currently studying the differences of objects and primitive data types in general and came across this article on W3schools.

Direct quote from w3schools.com:

> **JavaScript Numbers are Always 64-bit Floating Point**
>
> Unlike many other programming languages, JavaScript does not define different types of numbers, like integers, short, long, floating-point etc.
>
> JavaScript numbers are always stored as double precision floating point numbers, following the international IEEE 754 standard.
>
> This format stores numbers in 64 bits, where the number (the fraction) is stored in bits 0 to 51, the exponent in bits 52 to 62, and the sign in bit 63

In simple terms, could someone give me an example of this as a concept?
Specifically, what exactly does this mean in the totality of programming in comparison to other languages (like C++ or Java).

Comment: it means all numbers are IEEE doubles.

Comment: It means that you don't have to care whether your number is an integer, a double or something else

Comment: Integer math is a lot faster than floating point math.  So, be aware that some integer tricks used successfully in languages that support different types of numeric data, might not work so well in Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press F12 to fire the developer tools in your browser, then go to the console and execute the following:

```
typeof 1234
typeof 2e32
typeof 12.34
typeof 12.34e56
```

In all cases you will get `"number"`. No matter whether your value is an integer number (small or big) or a decimal number (again, small or big enough to need scientific notation), the language exposes just one type to represent all of them.

Compare this with [the numeric types exposed by by .NET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7OrE.png) ([source](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpNumericDataTypes.aspx)), you can see that there is a whole range of types to choose from depending on the size and type of the numbers you work with.

Does this mean that JavaScript is in some way better or worse than .NET (or Java or any other language with a similar offer of types)? Not necessarily. They are different languages for different purposes, and balance complexity vs features differenly.

Comment: It’s probably worth noting that JavaScript supports [Typed Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray) which can distinguish specific number types.

Comment: This made a lot of sense, thank you so much Obsoletely. :)

Comment: @KennethStevenMcAuslandJr. You're welcome! If that answer was useful for you, would you be so kind to mark it as accepted please?

Comment: @Obsoletely 

Mark as accepted? How? Sorry, still brand new to the community.

Comment: @KennethStevenMcAuslandJr. Click the checkmark beneath the voting arrows.